# Conversion from type 'Object(,)' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, excel, object, .net

I am handling/reading Excel workbook using VB.Net.
Everything goes OK if worksheet has less than 20000 rows, but if it is more than 20000 then it throws following exception.

> InvalidCastException Occured
>   Conversion from type `'Object(,)'` to type `'String'` is not valid.

My problem is that why it works some time and does not other time?
What could be the potential problem??

EDIT:
Code looks like this:

```
uArea.Digits = CurrentRow.Columns(AREA_DIGIT).value 
uArea.ValidFrom = CurrentRow.Columns(VALID_FROM).value.ToString()
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code - that's the only thing that tells us what you are actually doing, not what you say you are doing :)

Comment: @Sajidali143 would be glad if you shared your solution! just ran into the same problem..